# How can I add users to my Box app?

Tags: box

```
Dim userRequest As BoxUserRequest = New BoxUserRequest()
        userRequest.Name = "MY APP NAME"
        userRequest.SpaceAmount = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
        Dim user As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Box.V2.Models.BoxUser) = adminClient.UsersManager.CreateEnterpriseUserAsync(userRequest)
```

I created a box application ,but I don't know how to add user to that, the code I have tried but throw exception of '**`invalid_request_parameters'`** , and I don't want change my application access to 'All User'.

Comment: Is this Visual Basic .net Visual Basic 6 or VB for Apps, or some other language? At the moment you don't have enough tags to target the right audience for your question.

Answer (score 0):

User can be create as shown below:

```
 var userRequest = new BoxUserRequest() 

   { Name = "test appuser", 
   IsPlatformAccessOnly = true, 
    Role = "Collaborator" };

appUser = client.UsersManager.CreateEnterpriseUserAsync(userRequest);
```